# "Role" of cohomology of coherent sheaves in SGA 4.5, étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-theory

As the question title suggests, what is the role cohomology of coherent sheaves plays for SGA 4.5, étale cohomology? Why are they so important for the construction and establishing properties of étale cohomology? What are some of the main essences, intuitions, and theorems of the cohomology of coherent sheaves that are exploited or get "carried over" from the classical setting, in some sense?

Comment: Excuse me, but could you give an example of the usage of coherent sheaves in étale cohomology. I'm a total ignorant, but, as long as I know, only torsion étale sheaves or more generally mixed l-adic sheaves are used at all...

Comment: @user40276 I'm not quite sure myself, but multiple people have said having intuition wrought out of a good grasp of how stuff works in the classical setting a la cohomology of coherent sheaves carries over well to étale cohomology, and I'm hoping someone can talk about that. Maybe I'm way wrong.

Comment: In my novice understanding: I think the usefulness of studying cohomology of coherent sheaves on a scheme is primarily for analogy (although there are bound to be some direct applications of the theory). Coherent sheaves are the class of sheaves where cohomology works 'nicely' in the setting of sheaves of modules on a (separated and Noetherian, say) scheme. There are analogous classes of sheaves ($\ell$-adic constructible sheaves, etc.) for the étale cohomology which are the 'nice' ones in that setting. Many similar formal properties hold, and the derived functor formalism unites the two.

Comment: Are you asking about coherent sheaves for the etale topology? One of the first thing one shows (using faithfully flat descent) is that, essentially, $\mathrm{QCoh}(X_{\acute{e}\text{t}})\cong \mathrm{QCoh}(X_{\mathrm{Zar}}$ in the obvious way (namely if $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent on $X_{\acute{e}\text{t}}$ then its pullback to the Zariski site is a quasi-coherent) and that this preserves global sections. In particular, the etale cohomology is the same as the Zariski cohomology of coherent sheaves. In other words NOTHING new is gained by thinking about quasi-coherent sheaves

Comment: in the etale setting. I apologize if I have misinterpreted your question. Dorebell seems to think you're asking for the analogous objects in etale cohomology for coherents in coherent(=Zariski) cohomology. If that's true then, yes, I agree that for most applications of etale cohomology one is usually interested in the cohomology of a lisse $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-sheaf (or perhaps a constructible $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-sheaf).

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think the OP means that there's a deep analogy between coherent (maybe quasi-coherent of finite presentation) sheaves in Zariski topology and constructible (or maybe lisse, or torsion) l-adic sheaves in the étale topology. And he\she wants to make it precise. For instance, there's a Verdier duality in both cases and a six functor formalism. Maybe a precise answer would be something like a six functor formalism only exists for some kind of sheaves in a given topology such that for Zariski it would be the coherent ones and for étale it would be the constructible ones.

Comment: @user40276 I see--I suppose that makes sense, but I have no idea how you deduced that from the OPs question or their above comment. Anyways,  is there actually a 'six functors formalism' in the abstract? Namely, as far as  I know there's no abstract definition of a 'six functors formalism' to make precise the statement 'Qcoh is the largest subcategory of Ab having a 'six functors formalism' '. Is there one I am unaware of, or were you just giving an intuition about what sort of thing the OP wants? Isn't it true that in both Qcoh and constructible they are the 'six operations hull'

Comment: meaning the smallest subcategories closed under the six operations and containing an 'important subcategory' (vector bundles for Coh, and lisse Z_\ell sheaves for constructible)?

Comment: Since this question has gained 13 upvotes in 13 hours, I assume that many people are here who understand and appreciate it, but actually I don't understand what is being asked here (although I am familiar with the concepts of cohomology and coherent sheaves). Could someone explain this to me, in his own words? If I take the question literally, I don't know what to say except for that both notions of cohomology are actually the same, just applied to different sites.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm just trying to make the analogy precise. Maybe I'm totally wrong. About an abstract notion of 6 functor formalism, maybe something like definition A.1.10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5361.pdf would be enough (with some modifications, like dropping Poincare duality or forgetting the Tate twists). About these being in some sense the 'six operation hull', I think it's not exactly true. For instance, perverse sheaves have analogous properties but they're the heart of a non-canonical t-structure in constructible sheaves. Thinking better now, this analogy seems to be a little forced

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ask two different questions, I believe.

1) When Grothendieck invented étale cohomology, cohomology of coherent sheaves was already well known, thanks to Oka/Cartan's theorems A and B, Serre's FAC, Gaga, and the Serre-Grothendieck duality theorems). It was also well known (Weil, already) that the invention of some cohomology theory closer to singular cohomology was one path towards the Weil conjecture. In some sense, cohomology of coherent sheaves was an insufficient prototype.

2) Coherent sheaves naturally furnish examples of étale sheaves and Grothendieck's descent theorems imply that nothing is gained by viewing them in the étale framework. This implies in particular that étale line bundles or étale vector bundles are the same objects than line bundles or vector bundles. This gives at least some étale sheaves, such as $(\mathbf G_m)_X$ or $\mathrm{GL}(n)_X$, whose cohomology can be computed; for example:
$$ H^1_{\rm ét}(X,\mathbf G_m)=H^1_{\rm Zar}(X,\mathbf G_m)=\mathop{\rm Pic}(X).$$

For $n$ invertible on $X$, the Kummer exact sequence 
$$  1\to (\mu_n)_X \to (\mathbf G_m)_X\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^n}(\mathbf G_m)_X\to 1 $$
gives rise to a long exact sequence which is the starting path to the computation of étale cohomology groups with coefficients in $\mu_n$.

When $X$ is an $\mathbf F_p$-scheme, the Artin-Schreier exact sequence
$$ 0 \to (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)_X \to (\mathbf G_a)_X \xrightarrow{x\mapsto x^p-x} (\mathbf G_a)_X\to 0 $$
allows to compute the étale cohomology groups of $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. One sees in particular that they vanish beyond the dimension of $X$, hence are insufficient for the Weil conjectures.

Comment: As it stands, the formulation is awkward since G_m-valued cohomology is presented as an instance of coherent cohomology.

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuRomagny. What I had in mind, as you probably understood, is that the first étale/Zariski cohomology group of $\mathbf G_m$ classifies étale/Zariski line bundles, and the latter are quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: Dear ACL, sure, the comment is apt.